# 301 redirect from .htm to /

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have just migrated to a WordPress website and my old site had URLs ending in .htm eg https://www.example.com/accessories.htm and I would like to 301 redirect all these URLs to root ie https://www.example.com/accessories/ - I have tried the following code in htaccess but it doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^\.htm$ /? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule as your **topmost rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(\S+)\.html?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,NE,R=301]

# remaining rules go here
```

Comment: That caused my whole site to go down - Error 500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: Sorry I had a typo. I fixed it now.